# Are there any reasons not to host a COM server in a COM+ application?

Tags: windows, com, interop, com+

The simplest way to transform an in-proc COM server into an out-proc COM server is creating a COM+ application. What are the possible drawbacks of doing it this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I really can't think of any reason to create your own container or use a 3rd party one (if any exist) in favour of MTS/COM+. I mean it does all the things you'd want:

- Lets you chose the distribution of
  COM objects to container processes.
- Lets you configure the account they
  run under.
- Monitors the container
  processes and restarts if necessary
  and can recycle them.
- Even allows you
  to host STA components in scenarios
  where you need multiple threads
  serviced by starting up multlple
  worker processes. etc.

It's hard to imagine doing better than that without spending 6 months or more on it.

Answer (score 1):

Turning the question inside out, I guess your anti-self might ask, "Why are there options besides the COM+ Server for an out-of-proc COM server? What advantages do these other hosting options provide?"

I don't have anything prepared, but I am imagining a table - with hosting options across the top as headers in various columns, and the particular attributes as headers in the rows.  you might evaluate each hosting option on each different area or attribute.

The main difference I see is in the administrative model and capability, and in the flexibility. For example, hosting a COM server in a Windows Service gives you the windows service capabilities - auto start with OS boot; the admin UI associated to services.msc (both administrative/operational things), and the flexibility to add other interfaces into that service (flexibility).